# OpenStreetMap finding different ways

Tags: openstreetmap

I am doing a project on OpenStreetMap to find the shortest path between two nodes.

How can I get different ways in OpenStreetMap if two nodes are given as input?

Comment: see the Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM) project: http://project-osrm.org/

Comment: That depends. Do you already have any local OSM data? You should if you want to run calculations on it.

Comment: Not sure about your question but you can have a look into the various routing engines: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing also not sure what this has to do with ubuntu so I removed this :)